# validate() function is not working in PostsController

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After submit the data from create view(PostsController) request goes to store method(PostsController)but neither data is validating nor throwing an error.

after removing the validate(), it is working and output is: 123

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
.
..
...
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
             ]);
       return 123;
    }

}


Output after the validate the data:

123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the validate method from the `$request` :

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
```

As said in the [docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

> validate method is provided by the Illuminate\Http\Request

You could also create your own request, run the command:

```
php artisan make:request PostStoreRequest:
```

In your request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Your **Controller**:

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
    { 
       return 123;
    }
}
```

I recommend you doing this way because you separate the responsibilities

> The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called, meaning you do not need to clutter your controller with any validation logic:

Answer (score 2):

Use request instead of this:

```
$request->validate
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)